# Launch browser using Chrome Or MS Edge

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have the VBA code to open multi URLs from column's cells in excel. Instead of using IE, how to change the browser to use Chrome instead.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim lrow As Long, lcol As Long
Dim linkcell As Range
Dim loopVar As Long
Dim IE As Object
   
Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.application")


lrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    
If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(1, 2)) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True
  
    For Each linkcell In Range("E2:E" & lrow)

        With IE
            If loopVar = 0 Then
                .navigate linkcell
            Else
                .navigate linkcell, CLng(2048)
            End If
          
            Do While .readyState <> 4
              DoEvents
            Loop
          
            .Left = 0
            .Top = 0
            .Toolbar = 1
            .StatusBar = 1
            .Height = 600
            .Width = 900
            .resizable = True
            .Visible = True
          
        End With
        loopVar = loopVar + 1
      
     Next linkcell
    
     IE.navigate "https://www.costco.com", CLng(2048)
    
    ShowWindow IE.hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
            
    Set IE = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Cross-site possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915325/open-google-chrome-from-vba-excel

Comment: "Instead of using IE, how to change the browser to use Chrome instead." - Configure the default browser to Chrome instead of IE, however, on virtually all supported versions of Windows that should already be the case.  All supported versions by default should have the Chromium based browser Edge set as the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simplified script that uses Chrome.
I have not tested anything, leaving the testing to you.
I list some sources that can help you develop the script further.

The script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim lrow As Long, lcol As Long
Dim linkcell As Range
   
Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
Dim executable As String = Path.Combine(path, "Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")

lrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    
If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(1, 2)) Is Nothing Then
    For Each linkcell In Range("E2:E" & lrow)
        Process.Start(executable, linkcell.Value)
     Next linkcell
End Sub
```

And here are some useful sources for moving the Chrome window
to the foreground (although it might not be strictly necessary):

- [How to use FindWindow to find a visible or invisible window with a partial name in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098263/how-to-use-findwindow-to-find-a-visible-or-invisible-window-with-a-partial-name)
- [How can I get a handle to a window of executed process in VBA?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0665c896-fdf8-48d5-a9e2-f66f865772ad/how-can-i-get-a-handle-to-a-window-of-executed-process-in-vba?forum=isvvba)
- [VBA - API Call issues with Show Window Activation](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-api-call-issues-with-show-window-activation.920147/)

Comment: Hi, there is error when copying your code to my file.

Comment: Yes, it's untested, you will need to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

there is error when putting the code to my file.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post this as an answer to your question, use the edit functionality instead. This way all relevant information is directly included in the top section of this site and not hidden in an answer below the question.